# Guiding Mathematica to perform specific simplifications

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like *Mathematica* to cancel out a specific term as much as possible.
One of my computations simplify to

```
((Pi*((l^2 + m^2 + 1)
      * ((l^2 + m^2 + 1) * Derivative[0, 1][w][l, m]^2 
         + Derivative[1, 0][w][l, m] * ((l^2 + m^2 + 1) * Derivative[1, 0][w][l, m] - 4*m)
         + 4*l*Derivative[0, 1][w][l, m])
      + 4*(l^2 + m^2)))
  / (l^2 + m^2 + 1))
```

I would like it to eliminate the `l^2 + m^2 + 1` term as much as possible.
`Distrubute` goes part of the way:

```
 (4 * (l^2 + m^2) * Pi / (1 + l^2 + m^2)^2 
  + ((Pi*(4*l*Derivative[0, 1][w][l, m]
          + (1 + l^2 + m^2) * Derivative[0, 1][w][l, m]^2
          + Derivative[1, 0][w][l, m]
            *(-4*m + (1 + l^2 + m^2)*Derivative[1, 0][w][l, m])))
     / (1 + l^2 + m^2)))
```

Now I would like to cancel out the two occurences in the numerateor of the second term. I have tried various combinations of `Cancel`, `Apart`, `Expand`, `Factor` and `Simplify`, but none of those went in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, starting with the last expression in your question:

```
Collect[
   (4*(l^2 + m^2)*
    Pi/(1 + l^2 + 
        m^2)^2 + ((Pi*(4*l*
          Derivative[0, 1][w][l, m] + (1 + l^2 + m^2)*
          Derivative[0, 1][w][l, m]^2 + 
         Derivative[1, 0][w][l, 
           m]*(-4*m + (1 + l^2 + m^2)*
             Derivative[1, 0][w][l, m])))/(1 + l^2 + m^2))), 
 1 + l^2 + m^2]
```

> $$\frac{4 \pi  l w^{(0,1)}(l,m)-4 \pi  m
>    w^{(1,0)}(l,m)}{l^2+m^2+1}+\pi  w^{(0,1)}(l,m)^2+\pi
>     w^{(1,0)}(l,m)^2+\frac{4 \pi 
>    \left(l^2+m^2\right)}{\left(l^2+m^2+1\right)^2}$$